# How to apply content sizing priorities to two views inside self sizing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have an UITableView with two types of self sizing cells. Below is one of them:

[image]

The light grey is the `UIView` while the dark grey is the `UITableViewCell`.

Both 2 labels and 2 buttons inside have top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints set to 0.
The top view has `top, leading, trailing constraint` and the bottom view has `top, bottom, leading, trailing constraint`.

This way I still get errors inside storyboard saying that for both views are missing Y position constraints.

I have tried to play with the hugging content priority and content compression priority for every view (labels and buttons too), but it is still doesn't display correctly. All of the text appears one on top of the other (the cell doesn't resize either, even if my other cell is resizing correctly).

What can I do to make this views displayed ok ? I am not sure I applied the correct content hugging/content resistance to the correct view.

Comment: did you try using UIStackView?

Comment: I am trying to avoid stack views, I had problems when using larger text for accessibility. They didn't display text correctly.

Comment: What are the constraints between the light gray views and the cell's `contentView` and between each other?

Comment: Top view: top 20, leading >= 20, trailing >= 20, align X. Bottom view: top to view1 20, leading >= 20, trailing 20, bottom to cell 20, align X.

Comment: make trailing <= 20 for both views

Comment: also set vertical content hugging priority for both labels to 1000

Comment: @Sh_Khan: that does not work, I still have the two errors plus more because of the <= for trailing.

Comment: literally I reproduced what you have commented and said in question with no errors

Comment: @Sh_Khan: inside a tableview cell ?

Comment: yes ............

Comment: You can answer the question then, and I'll double check and then I can accept it.

Comment: tell me if there is any problem

Comment: @Kobe One simple way to fix this is by setting the content Hugging Priority for the Second view to <250 and one of the view in Second view to <250.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it's not on GitHub [TableViewCell](http://www.mediafire.com/file/uonvpwghucqq5u9/kkk.rar)

[image]